# Access key/value in a paired-bar-chart - D3.js

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, key-value, javascript-objects

I'm attempting to make a Paired Bar Graph between *glob* and *local* within my JS Object/Array. I've made bar graphs in D3 previously, but haven't used objects. I'm finding it difficult to access the correct data.

Eventually, the *keyword* data will be used in the axis. And the *cpc* will be used as a tooltip.

Here's the code that I have so far: ([or see my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/juY5E/1/))

```
var w = 600;
var h = 400;

var colors = ["#377EB8", "#4DAF4A"];

var dataset = {"keyword": ["payday loans", "title loans", "personal loans"],
            "glob": ["1500000", "165000", "550000"],
            "local": ["673000", "165000", "301000"],
            "cpc": ["14.11", "12.53", "6.14"]   
};


var series = 2; // Global & Local

var x0Scale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(d3.range(dataset.glob.length))
            .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05); 


var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {return d.glob;})]) 
            .range([0, h]);

var glob = function(d) {
    return d.glob;
};

//SVG element
var svg = d3.select("#searchVolume")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);     

// Graph Bars
svg.selectAll("rect") 
    .data(dataset, glob) //access the series here?
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i){
        return x0Scale(i);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return h - yScale(d.glob);
    })
    .attr("width", x0Scale.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.glob); // ***************
    })
    .attr("fill", colors[1]);
```

Currently, the chart doesn't get populated. I assume I am not accessing values correctly. I'm simply trying to get data from *glob* to make sure I'm accessing things correctly - and then from there I was going to populate both series, etc. Is my issue not accessing key/values correctly?

Comment: I"m aware that my JSFiddle does not work yet. That's part of the reason I'm posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/juY5E/2/

I was able to get three bars by changing `.data(dataset, glob)` to `.data(dataset.glob)` and then changing `d.glob` to `+d` for the 'y' attr, the 'height' attr and in yScale.domain

to be able to switch between glob and local, you may want to restructure the data.

Comment: Good work. I had tried something similar, but not the `+d` part. I think I just returned d. So is that just concatenating?

Comment: And what do you mean _to switch between glob and local, you may want to restructure the data_? Eventually I plan on pairing Glob & Local into a set, and having them display side by side as a paired bar chart.

Comment: RE +d - yes, it will concatenate, or return NaN, depending on the situation. As for the data structure comment, I misunderstood your objective. I left a longer comment about d3 data structures at your other question.